# The use of the triple exclamation mark

Tags: javascript

Looking through the source code of one of our projects, I've found some amount of places where we're using three exclamation marks in conditional statements, like so:

```
if (!!!someVar) {
    // ...
}
```

Now, I understand that this isn't some kind of rarely used operator, it's just three negations in a row, like `!(!(!someVar)))`. I don't understand what's the use of it - in my opinion it can safely be replaced with single exclamation mark. Following are my attempts to find a case when `!!!a` isn't equal to `!a` (taken straight from the google chrome console):

```
var a = ''
""
!!!a === !a
true
a = 'string'
"string"
!!!a === !a
true
a = null
null
!!!a === !a
true
a = 12
12
!!!a === !a
true
a = {b: 1}
Object {b: 1}
!!!a.c === !a.c // a.c is undefined here
true
a = []
[]
!!!a === !a
true
a = [1,2]
[1, 2]
!!!a === !a
true
```

Am I missing some rare (or obvious) case?

Comment: Based on the answers given [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-not-not-operator-in-javascript) it seems that `!!` is a shorthand way to "cast to Boolean", and thus `!!!` casts to the negated Boolean. Like you, I can't think of a time when a single `!` would not do just as well...

Comment: I'd say it probably just got "simplified" into that expression by manually removing parens.

Comment: Perhaps someone thought that three exclamation marks would be more visible than one?

Comment: Nope. `!a` is already a boolean, so `!a`, `!!!a`, `!!!!!a`, etc. are all identical.

Comment: People will say it's for readability but it's really not more readable. Really isn't an argument that makes any sense as to why you would use 3 exclamation points. If 3 exclamation points is more readable than 1, then 5 should be more readable than 3? Why not just use 10001 exclamation points for maximum readability?

Answer (score 141, accepted):

There is no difference between `!a` and `!!!a`, since `!!!a` is just `!!(!a)` and because `!a` is a boolean, `!!(!a)` is just its double negation, therefore the same.

Comment: I decided to delete my post in this thread since it was misleading. I'd like to thank **aga** and **@jason-goemaat** for rectifying my mistakes in their comments. I'm commenting here, becouse above is the most straightforward and correct answer. Cheers!

Comment: And if a is null ? and you want only false value. !a return true and !!!a false ?

Comment: @Dujard `!!!null` is true. One exclamation will always be the same as three.

Comment: @Dujard `!!!null` is true. One exclamation will always be the same as three.

Comment: in short the OP's colleagues never gave any thought to what they were writing. using 3x is useless.

Comment: Technically, there is no difference. But, as [@zoidbergseasharp is pointing out in their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57828405/2445204), it can be used as an indication to the human, that the original value was not a boolean itself but a truthy/falsy value.

Answer (score 23):

In JavaScript, it's a way to show that what you are evaluating is not a *boolean* but a *truthy* or *falsy* value.

So for *truthy*/*falsy* values you either use `!!` or `!!!`.

And for *boolean* values you either use `!` or nothing.

This is simply for readability.

Answer (score 17):

It is the same as one exclamation mark. The key idea behind it is to improve visibility for the programmer. Compiler will optimize it as single '!' anyway.

Comment: Interesting interpretation of the motive.  In C++ I find that the readability issue is best addressed with **not** *(which has been part of the language standard since the beginning but people don't exercise it... you can't call a variable that, so why not use it?)*  Then again, I also use **and** / **or** instead of **&&** / **||** in "definitely C++  and not C code".  So I'm weird.

Comment: This answer works perfectly for JavaScript, particularly when used in http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp

Comment: Do you mean the interpreter? JS does not have a compiler right? Maybe on nodejs where they use GoogleV8 engine only?

Answer (score 6):

Consider:

```
var x;
console.log(x == false);
console.log(!x, !x == true);
console.log(!!x, !!x == true, !!x == false);
```

... the console output is:

```
false 
true true 
false false true
```

notice how, even though x is "falsey" in the first use, it is not the same as false.

But the *second* use (!x) has an actual boolean - but it's the opposite value.

So the *third* use (!!x) turns the "falsey" value into a true boolean.

...with that in mind, the *third* exclamation point makes a *TRUE* negation of the original value (a negation of the "true boolean" value).

ETA:

OMG!  I can't believe I didn't notice that this is a TRIPLE exclamation point question!  Even after it was specifically pointed out to me.

So, while my answer is hopefully useful to someone, I have to agree with the others who have posted that a triple-exclamation is functionally the same as a single.

Comment: That's all fine, but it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: I should have said a simple "yes" or "no"?  The answer to the question "am I missing something" is implied with the first line; "x is' falsey' but it's not the same as false".

Comment: The question is about the triple exclamation point, which your answer doesn't mention at all. While the answer can be determined from your answer by someone sufficiently knowledgeable with JavaScript, if the poster were that knowledgeable, they wouldn't have had to ask the question in the first place.

Comment: Hmm...I suppose I *should* have included the console output.  I've added that to help make things more clear.  I'm afraid I don't see how I'm not addressing the triple-exclamation point.

Comment: Oh, wait...yeah; I get it now.  Sorry for the confusion.