# Is !!!foo the same as !foo?

Tags: javascript

Knowing that `!!foo` gives you the Boolean value of `foo`, I have seen some programmers say that it's better to use `!!!foo` instead of `!foo` because you are changing it to its Boolean value first and then negating the value.

So my question is,

Is `!!!foo` always equals `!foo`? (`!!!foo === !foo`)

Comment: That's silly. A single application of `!` will convert the value to boolean and result in the logical negation of that. The result is **always** either `true` or `false`.  There's no reason to apply `!` twice more.

Comment: Yes. (and some more letters, because the comment has a minimum length).

Comment: I know it's silly, I just needed to ask this just to be sure... some people don't see that it's the same thing

Comment: It's a particularly indecisive boolean, one that's afraid to make the hard decisions in life.

Comment: while it may be a somewhat silly question, logical not is actually one of the very few things in JS, that allow no language abuse to get even close to changing the result, after the first step. There are ways to get e.g. `a !== a` to work, you can do weird things if results are strings (or even better, objects), but boolean not, no chance.

Comment: Very simply, if you know what one exclamation point does, adding more just switches between true and false. `!!foo` doesn't give you "the Boolean value" of `foo`, it gives you the negation of the negation of the coercion of `foo` to a Boolean.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The use of the triple exclamation mark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21154510/the-use-of-the-triple-exclamation-mark)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yup. Just for clarity:

`!!x === x` is not generally true, but it is true if `x` is already a boolean: "not (not true)" is true, and "not (not false)" is false.

`!foo` is always a boolean; if `foo` is truthy, it's `false`, otherwise it's `true`.

So if you substitute `!foo` in for `x` you get that `!!(!foo) === (!foo)` is always true. Removing the parentheses doesn't change the meaning, so `!!!foo === !foo` is always true.

Which means there's no good reason to write `!!!foo` in actual code. Just use `!foo` instead.

Answer (score 3):

I've never seen `!!!foo` used in actual code, but yes, they are always strictly equal.

The extra two exclamation marks just negate the boolean value twice, which always gives the same result.

Answer (score 1):

If foo is set as boolean then !foo will be equal to !!!foo , See the example and screenshot given below

```
var foo = true;

console.log('foo => '+foo);
console.log('!foo => '+!foo);
console.log('!!foo => '+!!foo);
console.log('!!!foo => '+!!!foo);
console.log('!!!!foo => '+!!!!foo);
if(!!!foo === !foo){
  console.log("Equals");
}else{
  console.log("Not Equals");
}
```

[image]

Comment: foo doesn't even need to be a boolean, this works for all `foo`.

Answer (score 0):

While you are correct, `!!!foo` would equal to `!foo`, I've never seen JS script using `!!!foo` before, and I can't think of a good reason to do that. You're gonna create code smell if you write this in your own code.

In other words, **don't do that.**