# What is difference in writing some object as !!! or ! in javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What is the difference in writing some object as !!! or ! in javascript.

var d is an object white may have some property.

`if(!!!d.c.l) or if(!d.c.l) what is the difference`

Comment: I have not seen !!! , it must be !! , !! Operator converts anything into a boolean value

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The use of the triple exclamation mark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21154510/the-use-of-the-triple-exclamation-mark)

Answer (score 2):

## There's no difference (in the result) between `!` and `!!!`

the `!` parses the value to a boolean of opposite type. The examples below make it more clear.

#### EG

```
const val = true;
!val // this is false
```

by doing `!` multiple times you just swap the value again.

#### EG

```
const val = true;
!val // this is false
!!val // this is true
!!!val // this is false
```

Comment: a good exmaple is if you have a function and return for example this `return someVariable ? true : false` so you can write it like this `return !!someVariable`

Comment: My mentor suggested I use this as I was using!


 if(!!nextProps.selectedView && !!nextProps.selectedView.selectedQuestion !== !!this.props.selectedView.selectedQuestion) {
      route(`/practice-question?clid=${nextProps.classCode}&cpid=${nextProps.chapterId}&tid=${nextProps.selectedView.selectedTopic.id}#`,true)
    }

what if i use single !

Comment: a single will make true false and false true. a double will make false false and true true. They are just opposite. most of the time you don't need `!!` its actually a shorthand for  parsing one type to boolean.